# Recursive function guess

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

$$
$$
I am having trouble with getting the right guess because the right side of the function is a constant. How do I get the right guess? I need to find the general solution

Comment: The general method is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205834/how-to-solve-linear-recurrence-relations-with-constant-coefficients. In your example the homogeneous relation (with 0 on the RHS) is easy to solve using the characteristic polynomial and it is then also easy to find a particular solution of the original relation of the form $an+b$.

Comment: I got the homogenoeous relation, but I can't seem to do the particular solution even if I am using A*n as the form

Comment: Keep trying: it's not difficult. There's a particular solution of form $an$.

Comment: If a constant $y_n=C$ doesn't work, try with $y_n=Cn$ (linear in $n$).

Comment: Alt. hint: $y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}=5+2(y_{n+1}-y_{n})=5+ 2\big(5 + 2(y_n-y_{n-1})\big)=\dots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth noting that the method of generating functions does not require a guess.  Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function.  Then the recurrence implies that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (y_{n+2} - 3 y_{n+1} + 2y_{n}) z^{n+2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 5 z^{n+2}.$$
So
$$(f(z)-y_0z^0-y_1z^1)-3z(f(z)-y_0z^0) + 2z^2 f(z) = \frac{5 z^2}{1-z}.$$
Solving for $f(z)$ yields
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{\frac{5 z^2}{1-z}+y_0+y_1z-3 y_0 z}{1-3z+2z^2}\\
&=\frac{5 z^2+(1-z)(y_0+y_1z-3 y_0 z)}{(1-z)^2(1-2z)}\\
&=\frac{A}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{B}{1-z}+\frac{C}{1-2z} \\
&=A\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1}z^n + B\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n+C\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2z)^n,
\end{align}
which immediately yields general solution
$$y_n = A(n+1) + B+C\cdot2^n.$$
If you prefer, replace the $A+B$ with a constant $D$:
$$y_n = An+D+C\cdot2^n.$$

---

Solving the linear system
\begin{align}
A\cdot 0+D+C\cdot2^0 &= y_0 \\
A\cdot 1+D+C\cdot2^1 &= y_1 \\
A\cdot 2+D+C\cdot2^2 &= y_2 = 5+3y_1-2y_0
\end{align}
for $(A,D,C)$ in terms of $y_0$ and $y_1$ yields
\begin{align}
A &= -5 \\
D &= 2 y_0 - y_1 - 5 \\
C &= -y_0 + y_1 + 5
\end{align}

Comment: @MichaelCohen $A=-5$.